# Icecast file not logging anymore

Tags: icecast, logrotate

I'm encountering the following issue while using  the following logrotate with icecast access.log :

- File access.log stay at 0ko for a random time and don't log anything
- Archived files access.log-20120601.gz are empty

this is my /etc/logrotate.d/icecast

```
/home/log/icecast/access.log{
# Les logs sont compréssé avant rotation
compress
# Fréquence de rotation par défaut :
monthly
# Par défaut, une rotation par jour est effectuée. 365,25 Jours par ans, nous concervons     donc
# une profondeur de 366 jours.
rotate 366
# En parallèle, si une archive est agée de plus de 366 jours, elle est détruite :
maxage 366
# Insertion de la date dans l'archivage des journaux.
dateext
# Lors d'une rotation, un fichier de remplacement est créé avec les droits 0640      appartenant 
# root et au groupe root.
create 777 root root
# Toutes les archives sont stockées dans /var/log/icecast.
olddir /var/log/icecast

}
```

Comment: The latest packages of icecast2 on Ubuntu come with a logrotate implementation already in place at /etc/logrotate.d/icecast2 so you don't have to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have resolved the issue, but looking at my logrotate file for Icecast 2 (which was installed by Icecast itself) the only meaningful difference seems to be these lines:

```
postrotate
    if pgrep icecast2 >/dev/null; then
        invoke-rc.d --quiet icecast2 reload > /dev/null
    fi
endscript
```

Which sends a **SIGHUP** signal to Icecast process.

Looking at [Icecast Documentation](http://icecast.org/docs/icecast-2.3.1/icecast2_config_file.html#log), there's a paragraph that explains that:

> Note that on non-win32 platforms, a HUP signal can be sent to icecast in which the log files are re-opened for appending giving the ability move/remove the log files.